# Legendre Transforms

Tags: legendre-symbol, variational-analysis

I want to show that the Legendre Transform of a function $g(x) = kf(x-x_0) + m$ for $m$, $k$ constants is equal to $g^*(p) = kf\left(\frac{p}{k}\right)+p \cdot x_0+m$ where $f^*$ is the Legendre transform of $f$.

I have attempted to solve this:

$$
g^*(p) = \sup_x(p^\top \cdot x - g(x)) = \sup_x(p^\top x - k f(x-x_0)+m) .
$$

My question is, can we say that this is equal to $\sup_{x}(p^\top x - kf(x-x_0)+m)$ where the supremum is now taken over all $x-x_0$?

If so, why?

Comment: must i use convexity of f?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Your question was very hard to parse, so I edited it. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).